# Is there an intuitive explanation why a circle is not contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We can prove that circle is not contractible (homotopic equivalent to a point). But is there an intuitive explanation of why this is so?

Comment: It has a hole. Clearly! ;-)

Comment: Advice: do not think of a circle as being embedded in a plane.  Think of it as a thing in itself.  Also think of a line segment as a thing in itself, not being embedded anywhere, and try to picture it contracting to a point.  Now try to do the same thing with the circle.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly reasonable question, especially given that the proof that $S_1$ is not contractible is actually not trivial. It is a duplicate, so it should be closed, but I don't think it deserves down-votes.